# Python when are imported files evaluated?

Tags: python, import, global

I hope the question phrasing is meaningful. What I am wanting to do is change a flat variable's value in a file, and have the files which have imported that file see the updated value. It appears that I can do this. For example:

```
#settings.py
VARIABLE = 1
def change_variable():
    global VARIABLE
    VARIABLE = 2
```

and

```
#main.py
import settings
print(settings.VARIABLE)
settings.change_variable()
print(settings.VARIABLE)
```

which outputs:

```
1
2
```

As desired. Although I was a little surprised since I thought maybe the value of settings.VARIABLE would be fixed after settings was imported. I would like to know whether I can rely on this behaviour. My question is thus also, when in general will the values from an imported file be "updated" or "re-evaluated" from the perspective of the importing file? How does it work behind the scenes?

I could of course just make a class. But I don't like the idea of settings, or any config, being an object. I prefer it flat. But I want the option to change the settings after import based on user cli input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the file `settings.py` is imported, python is done looking at the file. It now has a module loaded in memory, and if it is imported somewhere else, that module will be loaded there. The file is never looked at again after the first import.

Your function changed the value of `VARIABLE` in that module. You can depend on it being your new value unless you change it again.

Comment: This isn't correct. Maybe it applied to previous python versions, but not to 3.11. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the importing is done. Using `import abc`, when a variable is defined in a module, then any and all modules that import it, will update the original on write, and see the updated versions on read, as long as they access it as `abc.xyz` (assuming the variable is called `xyz`). Even the module that actually contains the original definition, would see an updated value. This is logical, because in all cases there is only a single instance of `xyz`.

If instead you import like `from abc import xyz`, then a local copy of xyz is created in the importing module, hence you access it directly as `xyz=5`, and in this case, only the local copy is changed. This is logical, because now there are multiple independent instances of `xyz`.

Personally I find it good that this behavior is as it is, it makes alot easy that otherwise would require complicated workarounds. So since you have both options, I think everybody should be happy, you just need to be careful how you are importing.

If you don't believe me, put this in a file, such as `importer.py`:

```
#! /bin/python

#this is the main entry point

import importee,third_party
from time import sleep

while True:
    importee.foo+=1
    sleep(1)
```

another file in the same folder called `importee.py`:

```
#! /bin/python

foo=0

from _thread import start_new_thread
from time import sleep

def watch():
    while True:
        print("importee sees:",foo)
        sleep(1)

start_new_thread(watch)
```

and yet another file called `third_party.py`:

```
#! /bin/python

import importee
from _thread import start_new_thread
from time import sleep

def watch():
    while True:
        print("3rd party sees:",importee.foo)
        sleep(1)

start_new_thread(watch)
```

Output:

```
importee sees: 0
3rd party sees: 1
importee sees: 1
3rd party sees: 2
importee sees: 2
3rd party sees: 3
importee sees: 3
3rd party sees: 4
importee sees: 4
3rd party sees: 5
importee sees: 5
3rd party sees: 6
importee sees: 7
3rd party sees: 7
```

so as you can see, both the module containing the variable, and another module that only reads that variable, both see continuously updated versions of that variable that is only being changed by yet another module (which is our main entry point).

Moreover, you can reload a module using `importlib.reload(some_module)`. This causes all global executable statements in that file to be reexecuted, unless guarded against using `if __thread__==__main__:`. This means the values of the global variables get reset, and the reloading module will see those differences (not sure about 3rd party modules but probably too, since it is unlikely that the reload causes separate instances of it to exist in memory).

What this means is that all the execution that usually runs when a module is imported, only happens once when it is imported. If that module is imported by multiple files in the same process, it is still only every evaluated once, unless one of the modules uses `importlib.reload(...)`. Moreover, the exact moment at which it is evaluated, is the exact line at which it is first imported by the first file that actually imports it, and this can actually be dynamic (depend on branching), because import statements can be present within function bodies. It is still however only evaluated once even if that function gets called multiple times.

##### Caveat

This only applies to variables that otherwise would get copied (such as when passed as arguments to a function). For objects that wouldn't, such as list/dict, even `from xyz import l` would still not create a separate instance of `l`. If you want a separate instance, then

```
import xyz
local_l=xyz.l.copy()
```

and for objects (the usual kind, whose type you define with the `class` keyword), the issue is a bit more complex, in that if `importee.py` contains the following:

```
class Spam():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=0

spam=Spam()
```

then if you use `importee.spam=...` during assignment, then you are replacing the object that `importee.spam` refers to, and everybody will see that change. If you use `from importee import spam`, then only the importer will see any change on assignment. But if you access and assign to members of `spam`, then those members get modified for everybody, irrespective how you import. So if you want a fully independent copy of spam from the get go, then use `spam.copy()`.